# configure nagios riemann integration for monitoring

Tags: monitoring, nagios, riemann

Hi i want to know how can i configure Riemann to forward events to [nagios](/questions/tagged/nagios) Server [This](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.nagios.html) gives the API for Riemann [nagios](/questions/tagged/nagios) integration but there is not enough info of doing it.I am new to Riemann and i am unable to figure out a way.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like the following in your riemann.config file:

```
(let [nagios (nagios {:host "localhost" :port 5667 :password "secret" :encryption TRIPLE_DES})]
  (streams
    (where (service "some-critical-service")
      nagios)))
```

It will forward the events from service "some-critical-service" to nagios. The message sent to nagios will contain the host, state, service and description from the event.

You can find more info looking into the [documentation for integrating with other systems](http://riemann.io/howto.html#integrating-with-other-systems) and the [api docs specific to the nagios integration](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.nagios.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply..the above information is available in riemann docs.But i need info about configuration in  nagios

Comment: I just read your question again and it's very clear to me it's asking about configuration in Riemann to forward events to Nagios, and not about configuration in nagios to receive events from Riemann. My answer includes links and information from Riemann docs but also a full sample config specific to forward to nagios, which I couldn't find in the docs

Comment: Sorry for not asking properly. Could you please give me more details as i have asked.